# Projecting ngFor template in <ng-content> isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 4 project and I'm stuck on a problem regarding templates.

Let me explain it better.
I have two components in my project:

- SectionCompontent.ts
- HomeCompontent.ts

These are the relative HTML templates

**section.compontent.html**

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="cards">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.compontent.html**

```
<section>
    <div *ngFor="let card of cards">
        <span>{{card.title}}</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

When I run this project, I expect to see the rendered content of *ngFor projected inside SectionComponent where `<ng-content>` is located.

Unfortunately, this is what I see on the DOM instead of `<ng-content>`:

```
<!--bindings={}-->
```

I added some static HTML tags like `<p>` and `<h1>` and they allowed it to work.

Can you help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `cards` is empty to me. Any error in the console?

Comment: Put some more codes for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer!! The `cards` array was empty, I tried with `*ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]"` and it worked!